# Read version of changelog file from variable for debian packaging

Tags: deb, packaging

I have **debian changelog** file. The Head of the file is as follows. `my-package ($VERSION) UNRELEASED; urgency=low ...`. When I rebuild the package I need to get the **version** from the environment **variable**.
Is it possible?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: i'm using 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is was created to be used that way. I mean practically within Debian/Ubuntu packaging workflow.

They usually have a preset version from original source archive by upstream developer. Then Debian/Ubuntu developer (who is making the Package) adds to it the packaging version as suffix. This version is put in a new/top entry of `debian/changelog`.

After all done the files are uploaded to repository, then binaries get built there. (without expecting such env variable).

What you can do, use `dch` (`debchange`) before launching the build. include the new version using cmd flags `--newversion` or `-v` with other flags to:

- Add new entry
- Or Edit last entry
- Or Replace the file completely

If you don't want to edit code:

1. Create a new changelog with a new name `<newchangelog-file>`
2. Then tell `dpkg-buildpackage` to use it instead, as below

   ```
   dpkg-buildpackage ... --source-option=-l<newchangelog-file>
   ```